# Stop evenmachine after all data loaded with many fibers

Tags: ruby, eventmachine, fibers

I tried get data from rest api using http requests and evenmachine. For this use [em-net-http](https://github.com/jfairbairn/em-net-http), fibers(ruby1.9.2p290). My pseudocode look like this:

```
  EM.run do
    Fiber.new do
      api_client.get_data_1
    end.resume

    Fiber.new do
      api_client.get_data_2
    end.resume

    ...

    Fiber.new do
      api_client.get_data_n
    end.resume

    EventMachine.stop
  end
```

Question: How stop EM after all data loaded? I counted requests but this bad practice. Is there any pattern to do this? I also used [em-synchrony](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-synchrony/) but this slower for me.

Thanks

Comment: I suspect your code is doing requests sequentially. No idea how em-synchrony can be slower than a sequential download. Please provide a benchmark with results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [em-http-request](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request/) and the [multi-http interface](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request/wiki/Parallel-Requests) which provides a call back for when all the requests have been completed. The example provided in the second link does pretty much what you're after.